# what is the difference between WHERE and HAVING

Tags: sql, group-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: What’s the difference between HAVING and WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where)

i am learning sql syntax and i can't understand this.

the second half of the question is a much more technical one. what is actually happening behind the scenes of the database between WHERE and HAVING? which one uses more resources? are  they same algorithm just applying to different data sets?

thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question.  I think many times over.  ex:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where

Comment: We're not `HAVING` any more of this! This is `WHERE` you need to look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Where* is in most queries and limits the records that the query cares about.

*Having* is used in "Group By" queries, and acts upon the *grouped* results.

Think of the `Where` clause as happening first.  If there are 1000 records in the db, the where clause might make it so only 80 matter.  And let's say that the `Group By` clause groups these 80 db records into (for example) 15 aggregate recordset rows.  Without the Having clause, you would get all 15 of these aggregate rows back.  The `Having` clause if for filtering upon these 15 aggregate rows.

Let's say you want a list of all the customers from Texas who made more than 5 orders last year.

- the `Where` clause to get all the orders from last year by people from Texas
- the `Group By` clause to group all the orders by customer (with a `Count(OrderID) As OrderCount` in your select clause)
- the `Having` clause would limit the customers listed to those having 5 or more orders.

Answer (score 1):

where is used to filter rows directly in tables. 
Having is used to filter aggregated rows after they've been grouped by.

Answer (score 1):

They are both conditional operators but HAVING relates only to an aggregate function on a GROUP BY statement.

Eg.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = 'bob'
```

Will return all users with the username 'bob'.

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Will return which usernames have been used more than once.

Answer (score 1):

- `WHERE` filters the rows resulting of the `FROM` joins. [Check out this example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).
- `HAVING` filters the rows returned after aggregating with `GROUP BY`. Checkout [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` is used for filtration, and in ANSI-89 syntax - joining tables as well.  You can ***not*** use aggregate functions (MIN, MAX, COUNT, etc) in a `WHERE` clause.  IE:

```
WHERE x.col = 1    -- valid
WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 -- invalid
```

The `HAVING` clause is also used for filtration, but you can only use aggregate functions for filteration.  IE:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- valid
HAVING x.col = 1    -- invalid
```

The `HAVING` clause can only be defined if a `GROUP BY` clause has been defined - you can not use a `HAVING` clause if using either `DISTINCT` or `OVER` (analytic function).  The `HAVING` clause is always defined after the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought of it as: HAVING is to groups what WHERE is to rows.