# Mysql how to use COUNT value of rows from joined table in WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

Like that:

```
COUNT(i.t_1) AS total_images
WHERE total_images > 2
```

Throws an error:

```
Unknown column "total_images" in where clause
```

If this way:

```
WHERE COUNT(i.t_1) > 2
```

Throws an error:

```
Invalid use of group function
```

How to do it right way?

If need i'll post full statement.

The meaning of this query to pick the 1 ad with the most photos inside joined(images) table.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WHERE clause can only be used to filter rows in the table / derived table on a row-by-row basis. To filter based on the results of an aggregation you need to using HAVING instead of WHERE:

```
HAVING COUNT(i.t_1) > 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, i'll have to read man about HAVING ;) will approve after 10 min

Comment: @Beck: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where - *SQL: What's the difference between HAVING and WHERE?*

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just looking for the "1 ad with the most photos", you might want something like:

`select i.t_1,count(*) n ... group by i.t_1 order by n desc limit 1`