# Difference between WHERE and HAVING in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, having, having-clause

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: What's the difference between HAVING and WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where)

I have seen various discussions on `WHERE` and `HAVING`. I still have a question: is `HAVING` used only when considering aggregates, or can it be used in more general terms: whenever you have created or aliased a field in your query?
I know that `WHERE` should always be used when possible.

Answer (score 10):

`HAVING` specifies a search for something used in the `SELECT` statement.

In other words.

`HAVING` applies to groups.

`WHERE` applies to rows.

Answer (score 7):

`HAVING` is only for conditions involving aggregates used in conjunction with the `GROUP BY` clause. eg. `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`. `WHERE` is for any non-aggregage conditions. They can even be used together in the same query. eg.

```
SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) FROM table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
    WHERE t1.score > 50
    GROUP BY t1.id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

### Update #1:

Turns out there is a non-aggregate usage of `HAVING` that I didn't know about. The query below which uses an alias only works with the `HAVING` keyword, not the `WHERE` keyword. See my test in MySQL:

```
mysql> create table my_contacts (
    -> id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    -> first_name varchar(32) not null,
    -> last_name varchar(32) not null,
    -> index (last_name, first_name)
    -> ) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into my_contacts (first_name, last_name)
    -> values ('Randy', 'Jackson'), ('Billy', 'Johnson'), ('Sam', 'Harris'), ('Lenny', 'Benson'), ('Sue', 'Flax');
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT last_name AS l FROM my_contacts HAVING l LIKE '%son';
+---------+
| l       |
+---------+
| Benson  |
| Jackson |
| Johnson |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT last_name AS l FROM my_contacts WHERE l LIKE '%son';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'l' in 'where clause'
```

### Update #2:

I've now tested the novel use of `HAVING` on SQL Server and it does **not** work. So this may be a MySQL-only feature. Also, @Denis pointed out in the comments that this trick only works if the column/alias can be disambiguated and it only works on some engines.

Comment: I am looking for an answer like this: one which definitively describes the scope of HAVING. The keyword in this answer is "only." That said, I'm certain I've seen a counter example to this posted on another forum, which left me confused. I will see if I can find that posted query.

Comment: @CuriousKen: Correct. The word "only" is carefully chosen. I can think of no valid counter-example which would cause me to change the wording of my answer.

Comment: Here we go... and I think this answers my own question: This works SELECT last_name AS l
FROM my_contacts
HAVING l LIKE '%son';    but the following does not:     SELECT last_name AS l
FROM my_contacts
WHERE l LIKE '%son';     note the alias.

Comment: @CuriousKen: Very interesting. You taught me something today. I've confirmed your example with a test in MySQL which I have included in my answer.

Comment: Re your update: it actually only works if it can be disambiguated, and only on some engines.

Comment: In that case might as well fix the syntax error in your first query, too. Where goes before group by. :-)

Comment: @Denis: Whoops! Don't know how I missed that. Thanks. Fixed. That's what I get for not testing. Good thing I tested the rest of the queries...

Answer (score 7):

The `WHERE` clause is used to restrict records, and is also used by the
query optimizer to determine which indexes and tables to use.  `HAVING`
is a "filter" on the final resultset, and is applied after 
`GROUP BY`, so sql cannot use it to optimize the query.

`WHERE` is applied for each row while extracting. `HAVING` extracts all rows then filter the result.

Thus `WHERE` cannot be used for aggregate functions, because they require the full rowset to be extracted.

Comment: Order by is actually applied after having. But voting up nonetheless, with the assumption you'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`HAVING` is used when you have a `GROUP BY` clause and you are trying to filter based on one of the grouping fields; `WHERE` is used for filtering otherwise.

eg.

```
select StudentName from students where Age > 20

select className, count(studentId) from classes group by className 
                                      having count(studentId) > 10
```