# difference between usage of having clause and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: What's the difference between HAVING and WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/sql-whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where)

What is the difference between using `having` clause and `where` clause. Could any one explain in detail.

Comment: Exact duplicate, man, don't be lazy!

Answer (score 2):

HAVING filters grouped elements, 
WHERE filters ungrouped elements.

Example 1:

```
 SELECT col1, col2 FROM table
 WHERE col1 = @id
```

Example 2:

```
 SELECT SUM(col1), col2 FROM table
 GROUP BY col2
 HAVING SUM(col1) > 10
```

Because the HAVING condition can only be applied in the second example AFTER the grouping has occurred, you could not rewrite it as a WHERE clause.

Example 3:

```
 SELECT SUM(col1), col2 FROM table
 WHERE col1 = @id
 GROUP BY col2
 HAVING SUM(col1) > 10
```

demonstrates how you might use both WHERE and HAVING together:

The table data is first filtered by `col1 = @id`
then the filtered data is grouped
then the grouped data is filtered again by `SUM(col1) > 10`

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE filters rows before they are grouped in GROUP BY clause 
while HAVING filters the aggregate values after GROUP BY takes place
```

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` specifies a search for something used in the `SELECT` statement.

In other words.

`HAVING` applies to groups.

`WHERE` applies to rows.

Answer (score 1):

Without a GROUP BY, there is no difference (but HAVING looks strange then)

With a GROUP BY

- `HAVING` is for testing condition on the aggregate (MAX, SUM, COUNT etc)
- `HAVING column = 1` is the same as `WHERE column = 1` (no aggregate on `column` )
- `WHERE COUNT(*) = 1` is not allowed.
- `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Having is for aggregate functions, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo
GROUP BY baz
HAVING COUNT(*) > 8
```

Comment: Is it that the having clause is for checking condition with groupby clause.?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

`Having`  is for use with an aggregate such as `Sum`. `Where` is for all other cases.

Comment: select SUM(sal) from saltable having sal >1000 This does not work.

It works with where clause.

Comment: You write `Having SUM(sal) > 1000`

Answer (score 0):

They specify a search condition for a group or an aggregate. But the difference is that HAVING can be used only with the SELECT statement. HAVING is typically used in a GROUP BY clause. When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause. Having Clause is basically used only with the GROUP BY function in a query whereas WHERE Clause is applied to each row before they are part of the GROUP BY function in a query.

Answer (score 0):

As other already said, having is used with group by. The reason is the order of execution - where is executed before group by, having is executed after it

Comment: that really makes difference.Thanq

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a matter of where the filtering happens.

When you specify a `where` clause you filter input rows to your aggregate function (ie: I only want to get the average age on persons living in a specific city.) When you specify a `having` constraint you specify that you only want a certain subset of the averages. (I only want to see cities with an average age of 70 years or above.)