# HAVING without GROUP BY

Tags: sql

1. Is the following possible according to standard(!) SQL?
2. What minimal changes should be neccessary in order to be conforming to the standard (if it wasn't already)?
3. It works as expected in MySQL, iff the first row has the maximum value for *NumberOfPages*.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Book
HAVING NumberOfPages = MAX(NumberOfPages)
```

The following is written in the standard:

> `HAVING <search condition>`
>
> - Let G be the set consisting of every column referenced by a <column reference> contained in the <group by clause>.
> - Each column reference directly contained in the <search condition> shall be one of the following:
>
> 1. An unambiguous reference to a column that is functionally dependent on G.
> 2. An outer reference.

[source](http://synthesis.ipi.ac.ru/synthesis/student/oodb/essayRef/sqlFoundation)

Can somebody explain me, why [it should be possible](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml) according to the standard?

In MySQL, it perfectly works.

Comment: What other DB are you trying it in? Oracle, MSSQL etc?

Answer (score 35):

Despite the [Mimer Validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/) result, I don't believe yours is valid Standard SQL.

A `HAVING` clause without a `GROUP BY` clause is valid and (arguably) useful syntax in Standard SQL. Because it operates on the table expression all-at-once as a set, so to speak, it only really makes sense to use aggregate functions. In your example:

```
Book HAVING NumberOfPages = MAX(NumberOfPages)
```

is not valid because when considering the whole table, which row does `NumberOfPages` refer to? Likewise, it only makes sense to use literal values in the `SELECT` clause.

Consider this example, which is valid Standard SQL:

```
 SELECT 'T' AS result
   FROM Book
 HAVING MIN(NumberOfPages) < MAX(NumberOfPages);
```

Despite the absence of the `DISTINCT` keyword, the query will never return more than one row. If the `HAVING` clause is satisfied then the result will be a single row with a single column containing the value 'T' (indicating we have books with differing numbers of pages), otherwise the result will be the empty set i.e. zero rows with a single column.

I think the reason why the query does not error in mySQL is due to propritary extensions that cause the `HAVING` clause to (logically) come into existence after the `SELECT` clause (the Standard behaviour is the other way around), coupled with the implicit `GROUP BY` clause mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 29):

“When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.”
The difference between where and having: WHERE filters ROWS while HAVING filters groups

```
SELECT SUM(spending) as totSpending
FROM militaryspending
HAVING SUM(spending) > 200000;
```

Result

```
totSpending
1699154.3
```

More detail, please consult
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57445/use-of-having-without-group-by-in-sql-queries/57453

Answer (score 5):

From the standard (bold added from emphasis)

1) Let HC be the having clause. Let TE be the table expression that immediately contains HC. **If TE does not immediately contain a group by clause, then “GROUP BY ()” is implicit.** Let T be the
descriptor of the table defined by the  GBC immediately contained in TE and let R be
the result of GBC.

With the implicit group by clause, the outer reference can access the TE columns.

However, the certification to these standards is very much a self-certification these days, and the example you gave would not work across all of the main RDBMS providers.

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned so far, but the fact that the aliases defined in the `SELECT` clauses are unknown in the `WHERE` clause, but known in the `HAVING` clause, may be (ab)used to avoid duplicating a non-aggregated calculation:

```sql
SELECT
    sid,
    start_date,
    start_date + INTERVAL (duration - 1) DAY AS end_date
FROM formation JOIN session USING (fid)
WHERE "2022-02-02" BETWEEN start_date AND start_date + INTERVAL (duration - 1) DAY
```

... can be rewritten by only changing the last line:

```sql
SELECT
    sid,
    start_date,
    start_date + INTERVAL (duration - 1) DAY AS end_date
FROM formation JOIN session USING (fid)
HAVING "2022-02-02" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Tested on MySQL.

**NB.** AFAIK, the conventional alternative would be:

```sql
WITH SessionDates AS (
    SELECT 
        sid, 
        start_date, 
        start_date + INTERVAL (duration - 1) DAY as end_date
    FROM 
        formation JOIN session USING (fid)
)
SELECT 
    sid,
    start_date,
    end_date
FROM 
    SessionDates
WHERE 
    "2022-02-02" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes We can write the SQL query without Group by but write the aggregate function
in our query.

```
select sum(Salary) from ibs having max(Salary)>1000
```