# MySQL HAVING Clause return empty set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table below, and I need to write code that extract the rows with budget greater than the average budget.

```
+------+-----------------+--------+
| Code | Name            | Budget |
+------+-----------------+--------+
|   14 | IT              |  65000 |
|   37 | Accounting      |  15000 |
|   59 | Human Resources | 240000 |
|   77 | Research        |  55000 |
+------+-----------------+--------+
```

I know this works:

```
SELECT * FROM Departments WHERE Budget > (SELECT AVG(Budget) FROM Departments);
```

but this looks ugly. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330840/mysql-invalid-use-of-group-function) seems to suggest `having` clause can simplify the query into:

```
SELECT * FROM Departments HAVING Budget > AVG(Budget);
```

but it returns empty set. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `AVG()` is aggregation function which should be used `GROUP BY` or with other Aggregation functions.
If not, `SELECT` would returns single row. for example:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+--------+
| code | budget |
+------+--------+
|   14 |  65000 |
|   37 |  15000 |
|   59 | 240000 |
|   77 |  55000 |
+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT code, budget, AVG(budget) FROM test;
+------+--------+-------------+
| code | budget | AVG(budget) |
+------+--------+-------------+
|   14 |  65000 |  93750.0000 | we got one row.
+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this case, `HAVING budget > AVG(budget)` means `65000 > 93750` which is false, so that returns empty list.

Your first attampt does not look like 'ugly' ;)

Comment: This is a VERY good reason why SQL Server doesn't allow this construction (`SELECT *, AVG(BUDGET) FROM Departments`)

Comment: @Nizam I agree with you. I love MySQL but I hate MySQL's strange non-standard `GROUP BY` behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In mySQL, having an aggregation column with `SELECT *` will return the first row only.

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41864e/2/0) shows that:

```
SELECT *, AVG(BUDGET) FROM Departments;
```

will return only the first row and the average of budget of all rows.

Then, as in your first row, the budget is smaller than the average of budgets, it will return no rows.

I believe your *UGLY* (I don't think it is ugly) query is a good solution for this.