# Aggregate function after HAVING clause returning empty set

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

**WARNING**: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277818/mysql-having-clause-return-empty-set) question -- It is **NOT** like mine because I added a `GROUP BY` clause in my query and it is still not working.

---

I need to select the maximum value of the temporary column `project_count`.

This is the query:

```
SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*) AS project_count FROM Employees WHERE project_level = 'L1' AND YEAR(Employees.project_date) = '2017' GROUP BY employee_id HAVING project_count = MAX(project_count);
```

If I remove the `HAVING` clause, the output is like the following:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| employee_id | project_count |
+-------------+---------------+
|           1 |             2 |
|           2 |             1 |
|           3 |             3 |
|           5 |             1 |
+-------------+---------------+
```

However, if I include the `HAVING` clause (which I need to use to know the maximum value of `project_count`), the output is an empty set; but it should be like the following:

```
+-------------+---------------+
| employee_id | project_count |
+-------------+---------------+
|           3 |             3 |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You have two "layers" of grouping but are only specifying one; remember that `MAX(project_count)` is the same as `MAX(COUNT(*))`, grouped by employee_id. I'm surprised MySQL didn't reject the query; and that it decided to return no rows instead of all of them when it accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want just one row with max count, you can use `limit`:

```
select employee_id, COUNT(*) as project_count
from Employees
where project_level = 'L1'
    and YEAR(Employees.project_date) = 2017
group by employee_id
order by project_count desc limit 1
```

If you want all of them with max count:

```
select employee_id, COUNT(*) as project_count
from Employees
where project_level = 'L1'
    and YEAR(Employees.project_date) = 2017
group by employee_id
having COUNT(*) = (
        select max(cnt)
        from (
            select COUNT(*) cnt
            from Employees
            where project_level = 'L1'
                and YEAR(Employees.project_date) = 2017
            group by employee_id
            ) t
        )
```