# Convert SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

This shows the average occupancy (num_pax) of flights that have an airport of "SPAIN" as an exit

How can I convert this for PostgreSQL please?

```sql
SELECT AVG(number_pax) 
FROM flights f,airports a 
WHERE f.departure_airport=a.id_airport
AND a.country LIKE "ESPAÑA";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: As an aside, I have immense problems with tilde in my (rather old) RDBMS on windows 7.

Comment: You keep posting questions asking *others* to convert queries to PostgreSQL. That's not what SO is for. That's why your questions are getting downvoted. Do you have any actual problems? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the strategy seems to be working :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that Postgres uses double quotes for identifiers. You want to use the standard single quotes instead (that you should be using anyway).

I would also warmly recommend to use proper, explicit joins instead of old-school, implicit joins.

Finally, your `LIKE` condition has no joker character on the right side, so it is equivalent to an equality check.

```
SELECT AVG(number_pax) 
FROM flights f
INNER JOIN airports a ON f.departure_airport = a.id_airport
WHERE a.country = 'ESPAÑA';
```

Comment: Most databases use double quotes for identifiers so I wonder where this query came from? Or is it an assighment?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I would guess this was a MySQL query. It allows double quotes for strings.

Comment: And now I see the OP keeps asking people to translate queries for him ........

Comment: Does MySQL allow HAVING without GROUP BY? That's what the previous question was about

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: *Does MySQL allow HAVING without GROUP BY*: yes, [I think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by)