# Can GROUP BY be omitted when determining the duplicate rows in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, duplicates, having

[image]

The question is to return the duplicate rows from the table above.

My query is

```
SELECT *
FROM users
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The answer is

```
SELECT *
FROM users
GROUP BY id, name, created_at
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

What is the difference between those 2 above?

*I thought the COUNT aggregation is based on the all of the columns so I didn't add the "group by".*

Comment: Ensure that titles focus the question “what is the difference” is usually not refined enough.

Comment: The such a focused title can be used to search for similar queries (that answer the core question): https://stackoverflow.com/q/6924896/2864740 , https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57445

Comment: You need to say *what* is having a count > 1, which is what the group-by does.

Comment: @user2864740 I know MySql [can disregard the rules](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) when it comes to group by.

Comment: I'm not saying the query is illegal or an error - the 2nd query though has clear and obvious intent.

Comment: on a system with full group by the first query would run https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4e35d1da9854dd91473e5908e21dc520