# I don't understand why I cannot use HAVING in this statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
  f.*,
  q.day_avg_gmv
FROM
  fact_purchases AS f
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      ds,
      AVG(gmv) AS day_avg_gmv
    FROM
      fact_purchases
    WHERE
      istest = FALSE
    GROUP BY
      ds
  ) AS q 
  ON q.ds = f.ds
WHERE
  f.istest = FALSE
ORDER BY
  f.ds
HAVING
  f.gmv > q.day_avg_gmv
```

You can see the statement. I've tried to filter the gmv that is more than average. However, I've got this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "HAVING"

I know that I can solve the problem using this condition `f.gmv > q.day_avg_gmv` in WHERE, but I want to know why it's not working in HAVING.

Comment: There is no `GROUP BY` in your outermost query. (yes, there is one in the subquery)

Comment: syntactically, having goes before order by. After you fix the syntax error there is logic error.

Comment: `WHERE f.istest is FALSE AND f.gmv > q.day_avg_gmv`?

Answer (score 0):

in SQL you can only use `having` with `group by`.

you can not use it without `group by`.

Comment: This is not correct. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924896/having-without-group-by

Comment: we use `where` for filtering rows and `having` for filtering groups. there is no meaning when we do not use `group by` to use `having`. in your case it is better to put `having` filtering in `where`