# Sybase: HAVING operates on rows?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I've came across the following SYBASE SQL:

```
-- Setup first
create table #t (id int, ts int)
go

insert into #t values (1, 2)
insert into #t values (1, 10)
insert into #t values (1, 20)
insert into #t values (1, 30)

insert into #t values (2, 5)
insert into #t values (2, 13) 
insert into #t values (2, 25)
go

declare @time int select @time=11
-- This is the SQL I am asking about
select * from (select * from #t where ts <= @time) t group by id having ts = max(ts)
go
```

The results of this SQL are

```
 id          ts          
 ----------- ----------- 
           1          10 
           2           5
```

This looks like HAVING condition applied to rows rather than groups. Can someone please point me at a place is Sybase 15.5 documentation where this case is described? All I see is "HAVING operates on groups". The closest I see in the docs is:

> The having clause can include columns or expressions that are not in
>   the select list and not in the group by clause.

(Quote from [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands60.htm)).

However, they don't exactly explain what happens when you do that.

Comment: Are you sure this is Sybase?  I would think that Sybase would fail at the `group by id`, because `ts` is in the `select` list but not in the aggregation.  This looks more like MySQL.

Comment: Yes, this is Sybase 15. Sybase supports this - see the quote from the Sybase manuals I provide to ward the end of the question.

Comment: That is a more recent Sybase feature.  In MySQL, this would return an arbitrary value from a row.  It would not do what you expect.  I'm disappointed that another database decided to include this misfeature.

Comment: @Arkadiy, even if sybase supports it, it is a poor idea to use this feature as you will not always get what you expect as the mysql people have found out. Failing to completely specify the group by clause is a SQL antipattern. Not only is is problematic that you will get the results you want, it is harder to maintain. BUt really I am not sure what other result you would have expected. Perhaps if you tell us that we can point you to the code that will get it.

Comment: @HLGEM I am not expecting another result - I am hoping that someone can point me at a place in Sybase docs that would guarantee that this result is not accidental. As you say, I may not get what I expect - unless Sybase officially describes this somewhere.

Comment: OK, I thinkyour query could be simplified to 
select id,max(t.ts) from  #t t where ts <= @time group by t.id  which might be easier to find documentation on

Comment: @HGLEM - suppose there are more columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding: Yes, fundamentally, HAVING operates on rows. By omitting a GROUP BY, it operates on all result rows within a single "supergroup" rather than on rows-within-groups. Read the section *"How group by and having queries with aggregates work"* in your originally-linked Sybase docco:-

> **How group by and having queries with aggregates work**
>
> - The **where** clause excludes rows that do not meet its search conditions; its function remains the same for grouped or nongrouped queries.
> - The **group by** clause collects the remaining rows into one group for each unique value in the **group by** expression. Omitting **group by** creates a single group for the whole table.
> - Aggregate functions specified in the select list calculate summary values for each group. For scalar aggregates, there is only one value for the table. Vector aggregates calculate values for the distinct groups.
> - The **having** clause excludes groups from the results that do not meet its search conditions. Even though the **having** clause tests only rows, the presence or absence of a **group by** clause may make it appear to be operating on groups:
>
>   - When the query includes **group by**, **having** excludes result group rows. This is why **having** seems to operate on groups.
>   - When the query has no **group by**, **having** excludes result rows from the (single-group) table. This is why **having** seems to operate on rows (the results are similar to **where** clause results).

Secondly, a brief summary appears in the section ["How the having, group by, and where clauses interact"](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug122.htm):-

> **How the having, group by, and where clauses interact**
>
> When you include the **having**, **group by**, and **where** clauses in a query, the sequence in which each clause affects the rows determines the final results:
>
> - The **where** clause excludes rows that do not meet its search conditions.
> - The **group by** clause collects the remaining rows into one group for each unique value in the **group by** expression.
> - Aggregate functions specified in the select list calculate summary values for each group.
> - The **having** clause excludes rows from the final results that do not meet its search conditions.

@SQLGuru's explanation is an illustration of this.

### Edit...

On a related point, I was surprised by the behaviour of non-ANSI-conforming queries that utilise TSQL "extended columns". Sybase handles the extended columns *(i)* after the WHERE clause *(ii)* by creating extra joins to the original tables and *(iii)* the WHERE clause is not used in the join. Such queries might return more rows than expected and the HAVING clause then requires additional conditions to filter these out.

See examples ***b***, ***c*** and ***d*** under *"Transact-SQL extensions to group by and having"* on the page of your originally-linked docco. I found it useful to install the *pubs2* sample database from Sybase to play along with the examples.

Comment: Thank you for bringing the language below to my attention. That is exactly what I needed to see and was missing.

Even though the having clause tests only rows, the presence or absence of a group by clause may make it appear to be operating on groups

So when we have ungroupped, unaggregated columns in the select list, the group is no longer a single row - it's a number of rows. And HAVING works on each of these rows. Thanks!

Comment: @Arkadiy, no problem. I edited my answer and summarised some  additional information that I found useful at the time. I hope it doesn't confuse the original Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done Sybase since it shared code with MS SQL Server....90's, but my interpretation of what you are doing is this:

First, the list is filtered to <= 11

```
id   ts
1    2
1    10
2    5
```

Everything else is filtered out.

Next, you are filtering the list to the rows where TS = the Max(TS) for that group.

```
id   ts
1    10
2    5
```

10 is the Max(TS) for group 1 and 5 is the Max(TS) for group 2.  Those two rows are the ones that remain.  What result would you expect otherwise?

Comment: I do see that it's doing what you described. However, if HAVING operates on groups, what does it do with group where id == 1? Either whole group must be included because it has one row that matches the HAVING condition (ts = 10), or whole group must be excluded because it has a row that does not match the HAVING condition (ts = 2) . What we have in reality (and what you describe) is some rows from the group are included and some excluded. Where do we see that functionality described? That is my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands60.htm), it seems that Sybase use of columns in the `having` clause that don't appear in the `group by` clause is different from MySQL.

The example they give has this explanation:

> The Transact-SQL extended column, price (in the select list, but not
>   an aggregate and not in the group by clause), causes all qualified
>   rows to display in each qualified group, even though a standard group
>   by clause produces a single row per group. The group by still affects
>   the vector aggregate, which computes the average price per group
>   displayed on each row of each group (they are the same values that
>   were computed for example a):

So, `ts = max(ts)` essentially does this:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             max(ts) over (partition by id) as maxts
      from #t
      where ts <= @time
     ) t
where ts = maxts
```

The subquery is important, because the `where` clause gets used for the `max()` calculation *and* all rows would be returned.

I find this behavior rather confusing and non-standard.  I would replace it with more typical constructs.  These are about the same level of complexity and seem clearer to a larger audience.