# Is it possible to do so without using nested SELECTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

Suppose I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------------
ReceiptNo |    Date     | EmployeeID | Qty
--------------------------------------------
    1     | 12-DEC-2015 |     1      | 200
    2     | 13-DEC-2015 |     1      | 500
    3     | 13-DEC-2015 |     1      | 100
    4     | 13-DEC-2015 |     3      | 100
    5     | 13-DEC-2015 |     3      | 500
    6     | 13-DEC-2015 |     2      |  75
--------------------------------------------
```

> Show the tuples with maximum Qty.

Answer:

```
--------------------------------------------
    2     | 13-DEC-2015 |     1      | 500
    5     | 13-DEC-2015 |     3      | 500
--------------------------------------------
```

I need to use aggregate function `MAX()`.

Is it possible to do so without using nested `SELECTS`?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Not cross platform. Why do you need this?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM ... HAVING Qty = MAX( Qty )`.

Comment: @HannoBinder that isn't valid in Oracle or SQL Server.

Comment: It's valid in Sybase's T-SQL. Too bad it isn't in SQL Server's.

Comment: @HannoBinder I highly doubt it is valid in Sybase. AFAIK only MySQL is broken in this way. It is not valid in standard SQL to reference a column in the having unless contained in the group by or an aggregate.

Comment: @MartinSmith http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507825/sybase-having-operates-on-rows, or see the ASE TSQL Users Guide under "Using  having  without  group by"

Comment: @HannoBinder Thanks, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can't show the tuples with maximum Qty, using the `max` aggregate function while avoiding nested selects.

VR46 posted a nice way to do it without using nested selects, but also without the `max` aggregate.  A similar approach can be used in Oracle 12c using the `FETCH` clause:

```
select *
  from table
 order by qty desc
 fetch first row with ties
```

If you want to use the `max` aggregate, this is the way to do it:

```
select *
  from table
 where qty = (select max(qty) from table)
```

Another way to do it would be using the `rank` or `dense_rank` window functions, but they require a nested select, and do not use the `max` aggregate function:

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               dense_rank() over (order by t.qty desc) as rnk
          from table t) t
 where t.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this in `sql server`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Comment: @anonymous: It's bad form to change the question like that.  If you need `max`, then you'll need a subquery, which is exactly what you said you didn't want.

Comment: @anonymous and why do you need to use max? Is this homework? In any event that would be a nested select. `where qty=(select max`

Comment: @anonymous because your question has seemingly arbitrary and incompatible restrictions so at least one of them will have to go and understanding why they are there is important.

Comment: @anonymous: Not sure where you are going with this.  You said *I need to pin point my problem*.  But you haven't explained what that problem is.  I'm just worried that this is a classic case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I guess the selected solution has nested `select`.

Comment: @VR46, I didn't select that because of the solution. I selected that because of the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Not using `max`, but plain "cross-platform" ANSI SQL without nested queries:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.Qty > t1.Qty
WHERE t2.Qty IS NULL
```

Retrieves all records for which there is *no* record with a greater quantity in the same table.