# Difference between HAVING and WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Can someone tell me the difference between the HAVING and WHERE clause in the below context when i am getting the same results using both the statements

```
SELECT Table1.DEPT, Sum(Table1.SALARY) AS Comp
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.DEPT
HAVING DEPT="HR"
```

This goes with WHERE clause.

```
SELECT Table1.DEPT, Sum(Table1.SALARY) AS Comp
FROM Table1
WHERE DEPT="HR"
GROUP BY Table1.DEPT
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where

Comment: you will get the difference if you omit the group by clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally, the two are equivalent.

The `WHERE` clause is saying:

> Filter the data *and then* aggregate the results.

The `HAVING` clause is saying:

> Aggregate the data *and then* filter the results.

Both return the same result, because the filtering is on the columns used for aggregation.  Usually, `HAVING` uses aggregation functions; these are not allowed in the `WHERE`.

In general, the `WHERE` clause is going to be faster, because less data is being aggregated.  You should use `WHERE` in this case.