# Parameter in LIKE statement only returning exact values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parameterized query shown below that is supposed to return info about items that have a name like the parameter. However, it only works for exact matches

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
SET @name = 'bananas'
SELECT category, sum(netweight) AS NetWeight from PieChart group by 
category, name HAVING name LIKE @name
END
```

Since 'bananas' is in the database, it returns that info. If it put 'banan', it returns nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you miss `'%value%'`?

Comment: `%` is the wildcard character.  You'll want to search for ..`LIKE '%bananas%"`, or at least `LIKE 'bananas%'`, in the example you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wildcards.  In addition, you should use `where`, not `having`.  So:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @name varchar(50);

    SET @name = 'banan%';

    SELECT category, sum(netweight) AS NetWeight 
    FROM PieChart
    WHERE name LIKE @name
    GROUP BY category, name; 
END;
```

Comment: I think it should be `SET @name = '%banan%';` the OP does not say it should **start** with `banan`.

Comment: You are right thanks! Question: why use Where and not Having? they both seem to work

Comment: @coder123 The answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where

Comment: @Sami . . . If "bananas" matches, but "banan" does not, then the wildcard is only needed at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the wildcards in the WHERE clause:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) = 'bananas';

    SELECT  category ,
            SUM(netweight) AS NetWeight
    FROM    PieChart
    WHERE   [name] LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
    GROUP BY category ,
            [name]
END
```