# How to select only users with certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, having

In my database, I want to group by users, and I'm using three tables: Users, Categories and Articles.

```
DECLARE @v INT
SELECT @v = COUNT(*)
FROM Categories

SELECT U.Username
FROM Users AS U
JOIN Articles as A ON U.UserID = A.AuthorID
JOIN Categories as C ON C.CategoryID = A.CategoryID
GROUP BY U.UserID, U.Username
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) FROM Categories) = @v
```

What I want to select is only users who have published articles in each category existing.

I store the number of categories existing in variable @v, and use HAVING to define the condition (that is, only users who have published articles in as many different categories as there exist), but it doesn't seem to work since it will select all users who have published articles regardless of category.

I tried putting the condition to WHERE instead of using HAVING (I'm still not sure about the differences between the two), but I got the same result. I tried counting distinct CategoryID's from table Articles instead of table Categories too, but still got the same result.

What am I missing?

Table Users data:

```
  userid  | username
----------+-----------
        1 | Joe  
        2 | Sally
        3 | Anne
```

Table Articles data:

```
articleid | authorID | categoryid
----------+----------+-------------
        1 | 3        | 3
        2 | 2        | 1
        3 | 1        | 2
        4 | 3        | 1
        5 | 3        | 2
```

Table Categories data:

```
categoryid| categoryname
----------+--------------
        1 | sports
        2 | events
        3 | news
```

As you can see, there are three (3) categories, five (5) articles and three (3) authors (users). All three of them have written articles, but only User with UserID 3 has written articles in each category.

**My output:**

```
  | username
------------
1 | Anne
2 | Joe
3 | Sally
```

**Expected output:**

```
  | username
------------
1 | Anne
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: Try changing `HAVING (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID) FROM Categories) = @v` to `HAVING COUNT(C.CategoryID) = @v`.  At the moment your HAVING statement has nothing to do with the data in the select statement.

Comment: I think the root of your question might be answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where

Comment: @SazooCat thank you too, that solved the problem, but I had to add distinct to the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with the `HAVING` clause, you can use `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID)` in `HAVING` clause & the rest would be same :

```
SELECT U.Username
FROM Users AS U JOIN 
     Articles as A 
     ON U.UserID = A.AuthorID JOIN 
     Categories as C 
     ON C.CategoryID = A.CategoryID
GROUP BY U.Username
HAVING COUNT(*) = @v;
```

However, the `Categories` table is not needed in `JOIN`. if one user has duplicate category article published then use `COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: It's not duplicate article, but duplicate category article published.
Thank you, COUNT(DISTINCT A.CategoryID) worked!