# What is wrong with this query in mysqlworkbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

```
SELECT Product_Finish AS "Desk Finish",    
  AVG(Standard_Price) AS "Average Price"
FROM Product_T
WHERE "Average Price">300
ORDER BY "Average Price" DESC;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between HAVING and WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287474/whats-the-difference-between-having-and-where)

Comment: When quoting names in MySQL you have to use the backtick `\``, also you cant `AVG()` without specifying a `GROUP` (or it will auto-group everything in one row), so you have to figure out what you want which is probably not that.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- you use aggregate function `AVG()` but the query has no `GROUP BY` clause
- the `where` clause refers to an aggregated column; you must use a `having` clause for this
- identifiers are surrounded with double quotes; MySQL wants backticks instead

So:

```
SELECT Product_Finish AS `Desk Finish`, AVG(Standard_Price) AS `Average Price`
FROM Product_T
GROUP BY Product_Finish
HAVING `Average Price`> 300
ORDER BY `Average Price` DESC;
```

Better yet would be to use identifiers that require no quoting. Also, it is worth noting that, unlike MySQL, not all databases support column aliases in the `having` clause (in which case you need to repeat the aggregate expression). This is standard SQL:

```
SELECT Product_Finish AS desk_finish, AVG(Standard_Price) AS average_price
FROM Product_T
GROUP BY Product_Finish
HAVING AVG(Standard_Price) > 300
ORDER BY average_price DESC;
```

Comment: If you can provide a minimal example of your data and what you expect to extract from it, it will be easier to provide you with an useful answer. Right now we are just guessing here.

Comment: @RyanMehdian: please provide the full error message. Just the error number is not enough.

Comment: Write a query to show the average price for each finish available in desk products where the average price is greater than $300. Show the finish under the heading "Desk Finish" and the average price under the heading "Average Price". Order the results by decreasing average price.

Comment: Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cis_3050_pvfc.Product_T.ProductFinish'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @RyanMehdian: please run the query exactly as provided. Both above queries do have a `GROUP BY` clause.